# torque line rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I can't find it here so can someone help me with this regular expression issue.

my url is:

```
event/12345-12345-12345
```

but it can't with this 'rewrite rule'

```
RewriteRule ^event/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([/]*) /event.php?event=$1 [NC]
```

Debug or find an solution on my Regex:
https://regex101.com/r/WcSoFP/1

Comment: [Your pattern works alright](https://regex101.com/r/WcSoFP/1) even in PHP. The question is off-topic as there is no error.

Comment: This minus one is bad motivation. Because You can send me a edit option. Bad choice man!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape  `/` in your regex.

It should be like:

```
RewriteRule ^event\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*) /event.php?event=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: There is no need to escape a `/` symbol in a RewriteRule, it does not use regex delimiters. OP regex [works as is](https://regex101.com/r/WcSoFP/1) even in PHP.

Comment: Good to know @WiktorStribiżew :)

Comment: Of course it does, because your regex is equal to OP regex, which is also working.

Comment: I do prefer OP regex then :p php is so confusing with regex !